# how can we create a Jira Ticket based on Card count more than 10 in published PBI dashboard

Tags: powerbi, jira

I have card with count of table names, I need to create a jira ticket if card count goes beyond 10.

Comment: you need to add more information to get answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting into specifics is probably too much for this forum; however, as for general architecture, I think you may be able to use PBI Alerts and integrate them into a power automate flow that creates a JIRA ticket. The trickiest part will be the JIRA ticket creation which will probably require some kind of custom Azure App. The data driven power bi alert kicking off a power automate flow is a common pattern though so the first couple steps should be straightforward.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-flow-integration